# Using Html.Razor in Html.Raw helper in cshtml

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I want to use `Html.Razor` in `Html.Raw` but it's not working.

For example:

`var sourceString = "@var age = 25;@if(age > 20){<div>@age</div>}else{<div>@(age + 10)</div>}"`

`Html.Raw(sourceString)`

Output : `@var age = 25;@if(age > 20){<div>@age</div>}else{<div>@(age + 10)</div>}`

But, I want to like this. -----> `<div>25</div>`

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Show the context, where and how do you use that code?

Comment: @EmreCeylan: Solution doesn't trivial and described in this post: [Render string containing razor-code in view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35914085/6630084)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use rendering with the Razor `<text>` tag:

```
<html>
<body>
   <text>
       @{var age=25;if(age > 20){<div>@age</div>}else{<div>@(age + 10)</div>}}
    </text>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference: [Explicit delimited transition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#explicit-delimited-transition)

Comment: It's didn't work for me. Because, i want to use C# code(if-else) in the string that I send into Html.Raw.

Your string is ```<div>Alice</div>``` but i sent ```<div>{@firstName}</div>```

Comment: @EmreCeylan: Update your question to clarify want exactly you want: add `if-else` etc.

Comment: @EmreCeylan: I have updated the answer: See the **UPDATE**, please. Does this approach help to solve your problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't fix it. I'm reading this string from a text file, so I cannot use razor at that time...

Comment: @EmreCeylan: I have updated my answer with one more idea. Let me know if this can be used for your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want  the html to be `<div>25</div>`.You can use:

```
@{
    var age = 25;
    var sourceString=age>20?"<div>"+age+"</div>":"<div>"+(age+10)+"</div>";
}
@Html.Raw(sourceString)
```

result:

[image]